# How can we create our own formatting style?

Tags: css

When we write any new post we get text formatting options like Paragraph, Heading 1,.... Heading 6 and Preformated. How can we add our own style there.

For example I have below css style that I apply very frequently, so just thought it would be good to have my own style named "My Style 1" in the list, which I can quickly select any time if needed.

```
{ font-size: 30px;
line-height: 37px;
font-weight: 900;
letter-spacing: 1px;
color: #ee609c !important;
text-shadow:1px 1px 2px #0e0741, 1px 1px 1px #ccc;}
```

Please let me know how is this possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to add your CSS to both your front-end and editor stylesheet.

Next, we'll need to add a selector to the editor. I usually use the style select drop down which is normally disabled, but is perfect for this use case.

```
/**
 * Add formatting select to WordPress WYSIWYG.
 */
function my_add_style_select_buttons( $buttons ) {
    array_unshift( $buttons, 'styleselect' );
    return $buttons;
}
add_filter( 'mce_buttons_2', 'my_add_style_select_buttons' );
```

Finally, you need to add your selector to the options in this new drop down style selector.

```
/**
 * Customize formatting options for WordPress WYSIWYG.
 */
function my_tiny_mce_before_init_insert_formats( $init_array ) {
    $style_formats = array(
        array(
            'block'   => 'span',
            'classes' => 'my-custom-style',
            'title'   => 'My custom style',
            'wrapper' => true,
        ),
    );
    // Insert the array, JSON ENCODED, into 'style_formats'
    $init_array['style_formats'] = wp_json_encode( $style_formats );

    return $init_array;

}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_tiny_mce_before_init_insert_formats' );
```

Now when you select text and apply "My custom style" you're wrapping the selected text in a `span` tag with the class `my-custom-style`.

Comment: Thanks @MikeNGarrett this is what i was looking for.

Comment: Hi All, may i know what is the block name for paragraph, i tried with 'p' and 'paragraph' but both are not working. `array(
            'block'   => 'p',
            'classes' => 'joke1',
            'title'   => 'joke1',
            'wrapper' => true,
        ),
  array(
            'block'   => 'Paragraph',
            'classes' => 'joke2',
            'title'   => 'joke2',
            'wrapper' => true,
        ),`

Comment: I don't recommend using paragraph tags since the editor handles those differently. Try using div elements instead.

Comment: Thanks @MikeNGarrett once again. It did help.